# Cant implement Vitamio module version 5.0.0

Tags: android, vitamio

I downloaded Vitamio (last version, 5.0.0) module from official site, and implemented it into my project (in android studio, project structure - dependencies). After compiling project it works well. But when i started using classes from vitamio module - some errors were occured.  More precisely, this code part

```
mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
```

returned error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void io.vov.vitamio.MediaPlayer.native_init() (tried Java_io_vov_vitamio_MediaPlayer_native_1init and Java_io_vov_vitamio_MediaPlayer_native_1init__)
```

mVideoView is the object of class VideView from Vitamio module.

So, what am I doing wrong? How to use classes from this module? Using a previous version of the library is a bad variant (need only 5.0.0).

Comment: Please post your class in which you use mVideoView

Comment: Did you initialize Vitamio  by  Vitamio.isInitialized(getApplicationContext()); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dude, maybe add to your gradle file (app) in block sourceSets ndk libs references.

its like:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
    }
```

}